# Getting issue while using webview in react native Error evaluating injectedJavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, webview, wkwebview

I am using webview for trading charts,getting the following issue as warning and url is not loading.have given the code for loading.Also video URI is working in full screen but other uri are not working.

```
          {instrumentData.description == null ? (
                  <>
                    <WebView
                      ref={webviewRef}
                      source={{
                        uri: "https://github.com/facebook/react-native",
                      }}
                    />
                  </>
                ) : null}
```

```
    warning:-  Error evaluating injectedJavaScript: This is possibly due to an 
    unsupported return type. Try adding true to the end of your injectedJavaScript 
    string. Error Domain=WKErrorDomain Code=4 "A JavaScript exception occurred" 
    UserInfo={WKJavaScriptExceptionLineNumber=2, 
    WKJavaScriptExceptionMessage=TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 
   'window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage'), WKJavaScriptExceptionColumnNumber=38, 
    WKJavaScriptExceptionSourceURL=undefined, NSLocalizedDescription=A JavaScript 
    exception occurred}
```

Comment: Hi @Manish, are you trying to inject the javascript somewhere in the web view using webviewRef.injectJavascript("window.someFunc()")? If it is, please make sure to add ; true or ; return true at the end like  webviewRef.injectJavascript("window.someFunc(); true").

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you're having an issue with `react-native-webview`. I did some research and I found a link from the official https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/issues/341#issuecomment-466639820 that might help you resolve it.

I hope this helps!